# C# regex match all white space mid string if any there

Tags: c#, regex

I'm a bit confused on this one. A few possible strings I am splitting into 7 groups.

```
 string input = "05 28 55    +52 26 46"; // matches
 string input = "05:28:55.321-52,26,46.1"; // no match
 string input = "05,28,55.32  -52:26:46.1"; // matches
```

I have a regex creating 7 groups, with different delimiteders possible:

```
string pattern = @"(\d{2})[\s:,](\d{2})[\s:,](\d{2}?[.]?\d*)?[ \t]+([+-])(\d{2})[\s:,](\d{2})[\s:,](\d{2}?[.]?\d*)";
```

How can I get the regex to match the space before the + or -, if it is there or not? It works now if there is one or more spaces, but no if there is no space. How can I skip that if there is no space? The ? before [ \t]+ doesn't seem to be working how I thought it would.

Thanks!!

Comment: Use `\s*` for this or `[ \t]*`

Comment: Well, I feel stupid. That was easy.

Comment: To match horizontal whitespace, you may use `[\s-[\r\n]]` in a .NET regex, or `[\p{Zs}\t]`, and I think you also want to match the whole string, thus add `^` at the start and `$` at the end.

Comment: @rankind `Well, I feel stupid.`  That's one of the design goals of regular expressions.

Comment: HA, it certainly is... They are awesome when they work right though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `[ \t]+` to `[ \t]*` to match 0 or more .

`[ \t]+` means one or more
`[ \t]*` means 0 or more .

Comment: Thank you, I will accept this as the answer. Should have been able to figure that one out lol.